# I have some question about fiber in windows

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, fibers

I want to know about fiber that window provides.

Let's assume I created 4 fibers.

------------thread-----------------

fiber1 - fiber2 - fiber3 - fiber4

### ^

Fiber 1 now thread execute.

1. One thread can run only one fiber at the same time. It's right?
2. If a thread terminates fiber1, then another all fibers are terminated too?
3. I know fiber is Non-preemptive. Then if I want to switch fiber1 to fiber2, there is no way but call SwitchToFiber in fiber1?
4. If I call SwitchToFiber in fiber1 during executing some task, then fiber1 sleep immediately? or sleep after complete its task?
5. There is no shared space in fiber1 to fiber4?
6. And there is no shared space, then there is no need to lock in fiber. it's right?

I read MSDN documents, but I can't understand something. So I ask here.

Comment: 1. yes 2. fiber can not be terminated, it can be deleted via `DeleteFiber`. this call not affect another fibers 3. yes, only via call `SwitchToFiber` 4. even not sleep, this is incorrect, you just switch context to another fiber inside call `SwitchToFiber`. 5. what you mean under *shared space* ?

Comment: Fibers are only useful if, for a reason, you need to manually schedule threads in a different way than what Windows does (very unlikely). Most people never use them.

Comment: it means shared memory. i want to know there are memories that all of them(fiber 1 to fiber4) can access.

Comment: if they can't access shared memory at the same time,  there is no need to lock i think. this is right?

Answer (score -1):

`SwitchToFiber` is like `longjmp`, and `CreateFiber` is like an extended version of `setjmp` that allocates extra stack space. `DeleteFiber` is like a `free` of the context block allocated by `setjmp`. And most importantly, givers do nothing by themselves, and `longjmp` is like an extended version of C’s `goto`, e.g. similar to gcc’s “computed goto” extension, except that it can switch stack as it jumps. You could easily emulate fibers (non-portably) with `setjmp`, `longjmp` and some `alloca`.

Comment: i be say exist visible different between setjmp/longjmp and fiber. fiber have self own stack. setjmp simply save context (registers) and longjmp restore saved context back. with this we lost context (local vars, callstack, etc) from point where we call longjmp. need also allocate separate stack and switch it too for emulate fibers. also setjmp is save current thread context, when CreateFiber - create new context, instead save current.

Comment: The stack in fibers is of course what distinguishes them, but in terms of functionality – they are quite similar. All are nonlocal gotos, and their high-level semantics are identical. That directly answers all questions related to the fibers “pausing” or “running until” etc. The fibers can’t do such thing, because nonlocal goto wouldn’t either :)